# Standardizing and renaming variables in a data.frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to standardize all variables in a given `data.frame`, and add these standardized variables to the `original data.frame` with some *prefix* name like `"s."` (e.g., if original variable's name was `wt`, the standard one is `s.wt`).

My function below does that but I'm wondering why I can NOT access the new standardized variables? (*see example below*)

```
standard <- function(dataframe = mtcars){

  var.names <- names(dataframe)

dataframe$s <- as.data.frame(lapply(dataframe[, var.names], scale))

 dataframe
}
# Example:
(d <- standard()) # HERE I see the new standardized variables with prefix "s."

d$s.wt # NULL     # but HERE I can't access the standard variables!!!
```

Comment: You may need `lapply(dataframe[, var.names], function(x) c(scale(x)))`  Also, you are assinging multiple `vectors i.e. to a single column name?

Comment: Take a look at your assignment If you want as separate columns then `dataframe[paste0(var.names, "s")] <-  lapply(dataframe[var.names], function(x) c(scale(x)))`

Comment: Try `d$s$wt`. Tip: run `str(d)`. `dataframe$s <- as.data.frame(...)` creates a **new** df.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that we need to have new columns with suffix 's', in the OP's function, the assignment is to a single column i.e. `dataframe$s` while the number of scaled columns returned by the `list` is the same as the number of columns in the dataset.  So, we can use `paste` to create new column with suffix 's'

```
standard <- function(dataframe = mtcars){
  var.names <- names(dataframe)
  dataframe[paste0("s.", var.names)] <- lapply(dataframe[var.names], function(x) c(scale(x)))
  dataframe
 }

standard()$s.wt
#[1] -0.610399567 -0.349785269 -0.917004624 -0.002299538  0.227654255  0.248094592  0.360516446 -0.027849959 -0.068730634  0.227654255  0.227654255
#[12]  0.871524874  0.524039143  0.575139986  2.077504765  2.255335698  2.174596366 -1.039646647 -1.637526508 -1.412682800 -0.768812180  0.309415603
#[23]  0.222544170  0.636460997  0.641571082 -1.310481114 -1.100967659 -1.741772228 -0.048290296 -0.457097039  0.360516446 -0.446876870
```

NOTE: The output of `scale` is a `matrix` with a single column, By using `c`, it is converted to a `vectorr`

Also, we can apply the function on the entire dataset

```
mtcars[paste0("s.", names(mtcars))] <- scale(mtcars)
identical(mtcars$s.wt, standard()$s.wt)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Didn't know you could set names like that inside `[`. Very nice!

Comment: @rnorouzian  It is just that I wanted to have a `list` of `vector`s instead of `list` of matrices.

Comment: @rnorouzian Thanks, I avoid the `matrix` stuff because if you try to do with `sapply` etc., it could create confusion

Comment: `names(mtcars[, 2, drop = FALSE])` will give names.

Comment: @rnorouzian  Posted a solution for that